# UIImagePickerController not working on 4.0.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

Is anyone else having this problem?

After upgrading to new xcode+sdk 4.0.2, the library image picker does show some built in images, but it never calls...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
  didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
      editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo;
```

Instead it calls...

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;
```

No Idea what is going on. I am not able to load any photo now into my app.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting my Mac I saved a couple of images from the web, and I am able to load them. Buit-in images still dont open, but for now I am ok with my saved images working.